# Update property of property using sp.js

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sp.js

I'm using sp.js and I'm confused, how to update property of property?
For example I have:

```
Item: { 
    Title, 
    Image: { 
        Url: 'xxx', 
        Description: 'xxx' 
    }
}
```

I've tried `.load(Item)` and then `image = Item.get_item('Image')` but `image.set_item('Url', 'smthnew')` and `.update()` fails...

How to actually update Image.Url via `.update()`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: show your whole code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is Hyperlink or picture column.

To update it using JSOM, try the below code:

```
var clientContext  = new SP.ClientContext();          
var web = clientContext.get_web();          
var lists = web.get_lists();     
var oList = lists.getByTitle("TestList");     
oListItem = oList.getItemById(1);     
var urlValue = new SP.FieldUrlValue();
urlValue.set_url("https://www.google.co.in");
urlValue.set_description("custom image description");
oListItem.set_item("Image", urlValue);     
oListItem.update(); 
clientContext.load(oListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        console.log("success");
    }, function(){
        console.log("error");
});
```

Comment: Yes, looks valid, gonna try. Truly it is right. So each time I face some complex property I should find reflection of it in some sp object? Like URL object for this kind of field. Thanks

Comment: Glad i could help ! Please consider marking it as answer :) 
Also, you can can follow this link [Update list items using JSOM](http://pointofint.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-set-any-spfield-value-with-jsom.html)

Comment: Well, at least now I know it's called JSOM -_-